# updating two column from select statement?

Tags: oracle

I am trying to update two columns from `select` statement, but I am getting error message that says

```
ORA-00927: missing equal sign
```

Please, can anyone tell me why ?

```
UPDATE table1 a 
   SET co1 ,co2 = (SELECT COUNT (*),
                          sum(cost)/4
                     FROM table2 b
                    WHERE a.customer_id = b.cust_info_customer_id
                      AND tariff_info = 2);
```

Comment: `co1` and `co2` need to be enclosed with parenthesis, like so `.. set (col1, col2) = (select .., .. from ..)`.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Since he's using aggregate functions without `GROUP BY`, it's guaranteed to return just one row.

Answer (score -1):

Since you didn't provide any input:

```
create table table1(
  co1 number,
  co2 number,
  customer_id number
)
insert into table1 values (1,1, 1)

select * from table1

CO1 CO2 CUSTOMER_ID
-------------------
  1   1           1

UPDATE table1 a 
   SET co1 = (
              with table2 as (
                select level cost, 1 cust_info_customer_id from dual connect by rownum < 5
             )
             SELECT COUNT (*)
               FROM table2 b
              WHERE a.customer_id = b.cust_info_customer_id
             )
     , co2 = (
              with table2 as (
                select level cost, 1 cust_info_customer_id from dual connect by rownum < 5
             )
             SELECT sum(cost)/4
               FROM table2 b
              WHERE a.customer_id = b.cust_info_customer_id
             )
select * from table1

CO1 CO2 CUSTOMER_ID
-------------------
  4 2.5           1
```

Comment: Why is -1? I see no problems with this answer.